# How do I add a finite value to one component of a set of vectors

Tags: list-manipulation, vector

I have a set of (x,y) values in some *.csv file, when I open them with Mathematica to plot it some of the plots are shifted so I need to add some finite value to one of the components of every vector. For example:

```
 {{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}} -> {{a+h,b},{c+h,d},{e+h,f}}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something like `# + {h, 0} & /@ list`?